# Extract unique characters from a string with keeping whitespace between strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, whitespace

How do I extract unique letter occurrences in a string, including all spaces?

The problem with my code is that it only returns the first occurrence of the space:

```js
function unique_char(str1) {
  var str = str1;
  var uniql = "";
  for (var x = 0; x < str.length; x++) {

    if (uniql.indexOf(str.charAt(x)) == -1) {
      uniql += str[x];

    }
  }
  return uniql;
}
console.log(unique_char("the fox news newspaper"));
```

this prints to console:

> the foxnwspar

but my desired output is:

> the fox nws par

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Just check whether `str.charAt(x)` is a space and skip it.

Comment: Its doesn't work.. in this case all white-space will be removed from the string ..

Comment: Check whether it's whitespace and add it without doing the `indexOf()` check first.

Answer (score 2):

Add logical `OR` to check if the char is whitespace

```
if (uniql.indexOf(char) == -1 || char == ' ')
```

See working snippet below:

```js
function unique_char(str) {
    var uniql = "";
    for (var x = 0; x < str.length; x++) {
        var char = str.charAt(x);
        if (uniql.indexOf(char) == -1 || char == ' ') {
            uniql += str[x];
        }
    }
    return uniql;
}
document.write(unique_char("the fox news newspaper"));
```

Comment: this seems like the most efficient answer to me because only one function call is made to `str.charAt(x)` and only one use of the assignment `uniql += str[x]`

Answer (score 1):

if you're trying to preserve the whitespace, first check to see if it is `' '`, else then check if it's unique.

```js
function unique_char(str1) {
  var str = str1;
  var uniql = "";
  for (var x = 0; x < str.length; x++) {

    if (str.charAt(x) === ' '){
      uniql += str[x];
    }
    else if (uniql.indexOf(str.charAt(x)) == -1) {
      uniql += str[x];
    }
  }
  return uniql;
}
console.log(unique_char("the fox news newspaper"));
```

this prints to console:

> the fox nws par

Comment: Thanks @Jeff Puckett II.. you saved me.

Answer (score 0):

why not just remove the space?

```js
function unique_char(str1) {
  var str = str1.replace(/\s+/g, '');;
  var uniql = "";
  for (var x = 0; x < str.length; x++) {

    if (uniql.indexOf(str.charAt(x)) == -1) {
      uniql += str[x];

    }
  }
  return uniql;
}
alert(unique_char("the fox news newspaper"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for using hashsets as their lookup is O(1), instead of N as `indexOf()` is. JavaScript has a nice object called `Set`. Alternatively you can use objects as their keys are unique by nature.

For the real question, just skip the char in the string which is a space (equal to `' '`)

```
function unique_char(str1) {
  var result = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
    if (str1[i] != ' ') result[str1[i]] = 1;
  }
  return Object.keys(result).join("");
}

console.log(unique_char("the fox news newspaper"));
```

Comment: this is awesome, but I think the question wanted to preserve whitespace in the output

Answer (score 0):

You can init uniql with a space character and delete it at the end

```
function unique_char(str1) {
   var str = str1;
   var uniql = " ";
   for (var x = 0; x < str.length; x++) {

     if (uniql.indexOf(str.charAt(x)) == -1) {
     uniql += str[x];

  }
 }
 return uniql[1:];
}
console.log(unique_char("the fox news newspaper"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (uniql.indexOf(str.charAt(x)) == -1) {
  uniql += (str[x] !== ' ') ? str[x] : '';
}
```